# Proper way to show drop down on focus with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a keyboard accessible menu but I can't figure out how to get it to show the the drop down on focus.

I have

```
.main-menu li:hover ul,
.main-menu li:focus ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The issue is that when its focusing its focusing on the a that's nested in the li and not showing the ul. Tabbing is focusing on the a tags.

Here is my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/bxpe4/

Comment: The focus should be on the anchor tag (being the actual interactive element), not the list item.

Comment: That's not an 'issue', it's a very good thing that the browser focuses on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 8):

Another property that may be of use here is `:focus-within`. So if you do something like below, it should also work.

```css
.main-menu li:hover ul,
.main-menu li:focus-within ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The `focus-within` psuedo-class not only cares about the current element but all of its children as well. I think its a pretty clean solution to this problem and it worked for my issue.

Comment: [Great solution as long as your not using a Microsoft browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within)

Answer (score 4):

When tabbing, you focus the `anchor` inside `.main-menu li`, not the `list-item` itself.

There are two workarounds:

**a) using `+` selector**

```
.main-menu li a:focus + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

However, that makes it problematic to tab to other anchors (on tabs press, it should go to the first anchor in submenu, but it gets undisplayed, so nothing happens).

**b) using `tabindex` property**

That would require you to set `tabindex` on menu anchors to negative value (remove them from tabbing) and set tabbing to list-items.

[see Using tabindex demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfsNC/1/)

You would need to change the styling of anchors and list-items to show the red background too, adding a new selector:

```
.main-menu li a:hover,
.main-menu li a:focus,
.main-menu li.dropped > a,
.main-menu li:focus > a /* this one was added */ {
    /* your styles */
}
```

This however, is not really a good practice as focused list-items mean, that you can't access the anchor using keyboard. You could use JavaScript to simulate the event (bind keypress of the list-item to click on the anchor), in jQuery it would be something like this:

```
$('li[tabindex]').on('keypress', function() {
    $(this).find('a').click();
});
```

[see Using tabindex with event simulation demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfsNC/2/)

This is not an issue if the top-level anchors don't have any action (are only used for drop down purpouses), in which case you wouldn't need them at all.